# refresh DOM after jquery AJAX

Tags: jquery

So I have 1 map:

```
 <map name="diffmap1" id="diffmap1">
 <area  shape="poly" coords="76,269,50,243,51,221,82,255" class="diff diff1" onFocus="blur();" >
 <area shape="poly" coords="152,347,253,292,264,307,167,358" class="diff diff2" onFocus="blur();" >
 <area shape="poly" coords="93,244,164,215,171,233,97,264" class="diff diff3" onFocus="blur();" >
</map>
```

And jquery:

```
$('.diff').mousedown(
function(e){
e.preventDefault();
);
```

And $.post response:

```
$('map').attr('name', 'diffmap'+response.next).attr('id', 'diffmap'+response.next);
$('#diffmap'+response.next+' .diff3').attr('coords', response.nextcoord[0]);
$('#diffmap'+response.next+' .diff1').attr('coords', response.nextcoord[1]);
$('#diffmap'+response.next+' .diff2').attr('coords', response.nextcoord[2]);
```

So after each level tha ajax changes the map name, class and the coordonates.
The problem is that I can't click on the coordonates on level 2, because the doom is not refreshed after I updated the coordonates numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think using [delegate](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) it can work:

Your html:

```
<map name="diffmap1" id="diffmap1" class="myMap">
....
</map>
```

And jQuery:

```
$('.myMap').delegate('.diff', 'mousedown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: How can I unbind each .diff after click?

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically added DOM elements:

`$(document).on('mousedown', 'element', function)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('mousedown', '.diff', function () {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I unbind each .diff after click??

Comment: if I do .off('click', '.diff); it will unbind all the .diff coordonates and not the one that I clicked.

Comment: In your `click(function()` try using `.off()` this way:  `$(document).off('click', $(this), function() {});`